# Auto-populate a field during auto-generation of a record (with Assemble)

Tags: custom-object, create-records

My understanding is that, thanks to the installed package of Assemble, when a user registers for an Event, an Attendee record is auto-generated. In my production environment, every Event also has a required Event Category object. Assuming that I create a corresponding object on the Attendee record to hold the data, I would like the Attendee record to get populated with the Event Category so that I can auto-send email upon the creation of an Attendee record that depends upon which Event Category the user has registered for. I'm confident that I can create the custom object for the Attendee record; I'm just not sure what to do next. How can I get a custom object on a newly generated Attendee record to be populated with data from the Event for which the user registered?

Answer (score 0):

This is a question you should pose to the people who created the package who I think are [Fonteva](http://www.fonteva.com/Assemble). I can't see one, but the may also have a support forum where you could ask.

The package may or may not be designed to support extension in the way you want.